# Compiler Optimization

Tags: compiler-optimization

Should live variable analysis be performed before or after loop invariant elimination? I think it should be performed after loop invariant elimination, but cant justify.

Answer (score 0):

After. Generally speaking I would say live variable analysis should be performed **after** any operation that does code reordering.